# How can live position info of draggable element in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a draggle element in Vue component, and I declare the data in `data` function

```
data() {
  return {
    position: {"top":"116px","left":"238px"}
  }

}
```

I bind the `position` to the element

```
<div :style="position"></div>
```

But I find when I drag the element, the bind data `position`is not updated, the question is how can I get the live position info of the element?
Anyone could get me some clue?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign an object to the `position` CSS property. This won't work; `position` must be a string with a value like `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`, etc just like in regular CSS.

Try this instead:

```js
data() {
  return {
    style: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '238px',
      top: '116px',
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div :style="style"></div>
```

When the element is dragged, just update `this.style.left` and `this.style.top` accordingly.